# Substitute a string containing && with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've wrote some script for automated technical acceptance tests.
Since we're not allowed to write password in clear text, the script I used is associated with many variables, one of which is the password.key. 
Before execution, I get the `password.key=mycryptedpassword` line from a file and decrypt the password to use it in the script. I then try to replace the key with the password in a temporary file used by the script. 
This is where I encoutered my problem. I use the following code :

```
sed -i -e 's/$key/$decryptedPassword/g' json.tmp
```

It usually works fine, but one of the password I encountered is : `cl&&TiT8`

How do I tell to both sed and linux (I'm on redhat with ksh shell by default) to ignore those `&&`. Tried to backslahed it with one, two or three backslash but none worked properly. I'm worried I may encouter others weird password like this, what workaround could I do ?

**tldr** : I do that : `sed -i -e 's/$key/$decryptedPassword/g' json.tmp`. When `$decryptedPassword = cl&&TiT8`, that doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us an example of your input; ii) explain if `$key` and `$password` are variables or if they should be treated as strings. You are using single quotes (`'`) in your `sed` command and that means that `$var` will not be expanded to the value of the variable but will be treated as the literal string `$var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `s/regexp/replacement/` in sed, character `&` in `replacement` has the special meaning, any occurrences of it get expanded to the matched string by `regexp`.  So you need to escape each of them with `\`:

```
sed -i -e 's/$key/cl\&\&TiT8/g' json.tmp
```

You also need to escape `/`, `'` and `\` in both `$key` and `$decryptedPassword`.

How do you replace `$key` and `$decryptedPassword` in the sed command?

Comment: I think OP want to keep variable in host shell.

Comment: Actually it seems I tried with sed -i -e s/$key/cl\&\&TiT8/g json.tmp (without quote), which is why it didn't worked ><. Since the following works :  sed -i -e "s/$key/cl\&\&TiT8/g" json.tmp, I guess i'll just parse the password I get and escape any caracter that would cause trouble. Thxs to both of you !

Answer (score 1):

- `'$key'` will not evaluate `$key`, while `"$key"` will.

try

```
d2=$(echo "$decryptedPassword" | sed -e 's.&.\\\&.g' )
sed -i -e "s/$key/$d2/g" json.tmp
```

- providing neither `$key`, nor `$decryptedPassword` have a `/` in it
- note that you need `\&` in your replacement pattern, so you will need to first replace any `&` by this - while taking into account that you need to escape both `\` and `&`, leading to `\\\&` in the "*inner*" sed
- both `'s.&.\\&.g'`  and `'s.&.\\\&.g'` work by the way.
- with `'s.&.\\&.g'` ,  `\` escape itself, while `&` is replaced by `&` (through sed substitute)
- with `'s.&.\\\&.g'` , `\` escape itself, and substitute bring a '\&' (no sed substitute)

Comment: with $key=LPC.Admin and $decryptedPassword=cl&&TiT8, I get password=clLPC.AdminLPC.AdminTiT8 in my temp file